# Jackson - EnumValues serialization fails when dynamically adding enum values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson

I'm using `Spring Boot` and I have an error when it tries to convert a `Bean` into JSON with `Jackson`.

When this function (which is inside a `@RestController`) is called for the  first time, it works perfectly :

```
@GetMapping
public UserDto getUser() {
    UserDto userDto = // get the user 
    // userDto.getRoles() is an enum, let's call it XEnum, with 20 entries
    return userDto;
}
```

After this, a new value is added dynamically to the `XEnum`, so this enum now has 21 entries.

When the function above is called, I get this error :

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: 41; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 41 (through reference chain: ...UserDto["roles"]->java.util.ArrayList[21])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:296)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 41
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.EnumValues.serializedValueFor(EnumValues.java:79)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.EnumSerializer.serialize(EnumSerializer.java:132)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.EnumSerializer.serialize(EnumSerializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(IndexedListSerializer.java:142)
```

In my real case, `41` is the ordinal value of the new entry in the enum.

The `UserDto` class looks like this :

```
public class UserDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 475464704956181923L;

    private XEnum currentRole;
    private List<XEnum> roles;
    ...
}
```

Does Jackson has a cache of the enum and thus, it can't find the new value ? If that so, can I refresh it ?

**EDIT :**

I've found the origin of the issue.

Inside the Jackson `EnumSerializer` used during serialization, the `serialize` method looks like  this :

```
@Override
public final void serialize(Enum<?> en, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
    throws IOException
{
    // [JACKSON-684]: serialize as index?
    if (_serializeAsIndex(serializers)) {
        gen.writeNumber(en.ordinal());
        return;
    }
    // [databind#749]: or via toString()?
    if (serializers.isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING)) {
        gen.writeString(en.toString());
        return;
    }
    gen.writeString(_values.serializedValueFor(en)); // this line is evaluated !!
}
```

`_values` contains pre-resolved values and does not contain the new `Enum` entry.

Is there a way to enable `SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING` just for some `EnumSerializer` ? Because it may have side effects if I turn it on globally.

Comment: Please add `UserDto` model

Comment: I have added the relevant data.

Comment: Cool, thanks `private List<@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) XEnum> roles` should solve your question.

Comment: Compilation fails when I try your statement : `annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration`.

Comment: OK so add this `@ElementCollection(targetClass = XEnum.class)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private XEnum currentRole;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `EnumSerializer#serialize` method and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.EnumValues` class are marked as `final` it is hard to extend theirs behaviour. In that case, the easiest solutions is to write custom serialiser for `XEnum`

```
class DynamicEnumJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Enum> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Enum value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(value.toString());
    }
}
```

You can register it like below:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DynamicEnumJsonSerializer.class)
enum XEnum {
    X, Y, Z
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you !